# Gson custom deserializer for base class

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to consume a REST API and I'm using Gson, which would be great if some dozens of my model classes wouldn't require a custom Gson deserializer.

I think that I should use a custom TypeAdapterFactory but the documentation is poor and I'm having an hard time.

The classes I'm interested follow more or less this pattern:

```
public class APIResource {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer id;
    //Constructor and getter
}

public class B extends APIResource {
    @SerializedName("field")
    String field;
    @SerializedName("resources")
    List<APIResource> resourceList;
    //Constructor and getter
}

public class C extends B {
    @SerializedName("other_fields")
    List<Object> otherFieldList;
    @SerializedName("resource")
    APIResource resource;
    @SerializedName("b_list")
    List<B> bList;
    //Constructor and getter
}
```

Some times the `id` is contained in the JSON as a string named `"url"` that I have to parse.

The JSONs are quite complex, containing several objects and arrays and their structure is almost aleatory.

The `"url"` name could be anywhere in the JSON and I can't get it to work using `beginObject()` and `beginArray()`

I think my custom TypeAdapterFactory should be something like this

```
public class ResourceTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, @NonNull TypeToken<T> type) {
        if (!APIResource.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) {
            return null;
        }
        TypeAdapter<T> defaultTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                defaultTypeAdapter.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                //if the name is "url" use the urlToId method, else
                return defaultTypeAdapter.read(in);
            }
        }.nullSafe();

    }

    Integer urlToId(String url) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern
                .compile("/-?[0-9]+/$")
                .matcher(url);
        return matcher.find() ?
                Integer.valueOf(matcher.group().replace("/","")):
                null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you possible put a simplified example of JSON containing the keys that you use to determine the correct class? The cases your `ResourceTypeAdapterFactory` tries to parse?

Comment: @pirho you can find a good JSON example [here](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/151)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, if someone encounted the same problem this is my solution

```
public class ResourceTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, @NonNull TypeToken<T> type) {
        if (!APIResource.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) {
            return null;
        }
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegateAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegateAdapter.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                JsonElement tree = elementAdapter.read(in);
                afterRead(tree);
                return delegateAdapter.fromJsonTree(tree);
            }

            protected void afterRead(@NonNull JsonElement jsonElement) {
                if(jsonElement instanceof JsonObject) {
                    JsonObject jsonObject = ((JsonObject)jsonElement);
                    for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet()){
                        if(entry.getValue() instanceof JsonPrimitive) {
                            if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("url")) {
                                String val = jsonObject.get(entry.getKey()).toString();
                                jsonObject.addProperty("id", urlToId(val));
                            }
                        } else {
                            afterRead(entry.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }.nullSafe();

    }

    Integer urlToId(@NonNull String url) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern
                .compile("/-?[0-9]+/$")
                .matcher(url.replace("\"", ""));
        return matcher.find() ?
                Integer.valueOf(matcher.group().replace("/","")):
                null;
    }

}
```